# Display datalabels in two lines apexcharts

Tags: angular, ng-apexcharts

I'm using angular `ng-apexcharts` and I need to display the `datalabels` in two lines.
I try to use `"\n"` but still can't make it as 2 lines

```
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,       
    formatter: function (val, opts) {
      var duration = opts.w.config.series[opts.seriesIndex]
      var h = Math.floor(duration / 3600);
      var m = Math.floor(duration % 3600 / 60);
      var s = Math.floor(duration % 3600 % 60);
      var hDisplay = h > 9 ? h : "0" + h;
      var mDisplay = m > 9 ? m : "0" + m;
      var sDisplay = s > 9 ? s : "0" + s;

      if (h > 0) {
        return hDisplay + ":" + mDisplay + "\n" + "hours";
      }
      else {
        return mDisplay + ":" + sDisplay + "\n" + "minutes";
      }
       
    },
  },
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this structures: `["first line text", "second line text"]`

```
dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,       
        formatter: function (val, opts) {
          var duration = opts.w.config.series[opts.seriesIndex]
          var h = Math.floor(duration / 3600);
          var m = Math.floor(duration % 3600 / 60);
          var s = Math.floor(duration % 3600 % 60);
          var hDisplay = h > 9 ? h : "0" + h;
          var mDisplay = m > 9 ? m : "0" + m;
          var sDisplay = s > 9 ? s : "0" + s;
    
          if (h > 0) {
            return [hDisplay + ":" + mDisplay , "hours"];
          }
          else {
            return [mDisplay + ":" + sDisplay , "minutes"];
          }
           
        },
      },
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-donut-simple-forked-q3h9z) is working sample on codesandbox

And the result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer but it still not working 
Type '(val: any, opts: any) => string[]' is not assignable to type '(w: any) => string'.

Comment: What is your chart version?

Comment: @user13031827 I put working sample for you in this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/apx-donut-simple-forked-q3h9z?file=/src/app/app.component.ts). you can checked that is worked correctly. probably you need to update `ng-apexcharts`

Comment: @user13031827 Also see this [documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/multiline-text-and-line-breaks-in-axes-labels/) about line-breaks

Comment: this is what i have in dependencies  "apexcharts": "^3.27.2", "ng-apexcharts": "^1.5.12"
besides, i copied the example in the link (formatter function) and same error

Comment: @user13031827 can you create a stackblitz sample? my link worked correctly

Comment: @user13031827 show your `ChartOptions` class or interface

Comment: `import {
  ChartComponent, ApexAxisChartSeries, ApexChart, ApexXAxis, ApexDataLabels,  ApexTooltip, ApexStroke, ApexLegend, ApexNonAxisChartSeries, ApexResponsive, ApexPlotOptions,
  ApexStates
} from "ng-apexcharts";

;`

`export type ChartOptions = {
  series: ApexAxisChartSeries;
  chart: ApexChart;
  xaxis: ApexXAxis;
  stroke: ApexStroke;
  tooltip: ApexTooltip;
  dataLabels: ApexDataLabels;
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235585/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-user13031827).

Comment: Is there any way to add data labels like (left-side 2 lines text) + (right-side 1 line text with vertical align=center)?
We cannot use the html tag at all?